# Invalid parameter value for redirect_uri: Missing scheme

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, google-authentication, google-signin

I have hosted Jenkins on Ubuntu `14.04` server. Jenkins version is `2.46`. I am applying Google authentication on Jenkins. For this I am using [Google Login Plugin of Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Google+Login+Plugin?showComments=true&showCommentArea=true#) with version `1.3`. I have created Client ID and Secret ID through [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/). I created it using [this](http://www.tothenew.com/blog/jenkins-google-authentication/) tutorial. So while creating credentials, I entered following things:

> Name: Web Client 1
>
> Authorized JavaScript origins: http://jenkins.******.com
>
> Authorized redirect URIs: http://jenkins.******.com/securityRealm/finishLogin

After that I entered Client ID and Secret ID in Social security settings of Jenkins. Log in option appears successfully on Jenkins home page. But when I click on Login option following error appears:

> 400. That’s an error.
>
> Error: invalid_request
>
> Invalid parameter value for redirect_uri: Missing scheme: jenkins.******.com/securityRealm/finishLogin

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of debugging, I found the problem. The problem was, In Manage Jenkins ---> Configure System, for Jenkis URL, I was having value `jenkins.******.com`. I replaced it with `http://jenkisn.******.com`. And problem got solved.